# WSO2 API Manager node error when started in HA

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I currently have a HA setup for WSo2 API Manager that has the same for the gateways, external gateways and KM where there are two nodes for each sitting behind a load balancer. Currently all starts up perfectly until I start the second manager node I get the following error:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-06-14 08:15:01,780] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost]} - Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=500, location=/carbon/errors/error_500.html] java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.tracker.AuthenticatorRegistry.getCarbonAuthenticator(AuthenticatorRegistry.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil.getAuthenticator(CarbonUILoginUtil.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:352)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned error traces can be observed when the API Manager starts receiving Service endpoint invocations prior to complete server startup.

If you have configured a health check endpoint in the LBs than what is mentioned, then please update the Health Check URLs to `https://<HOSTNAME>:9443/services/Version` to overcome this behavior.

Further, these errors are printed during the server startup, and once the API Manager server is completely up and running, these errors will be resolved automatically.